# Нужна помощь по JS регулярка

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как правильно написать регулярку, чтобы можно было вводить в инпут любое значение кроме определенной строки (к примеру имени "Петр")?

Comment: @soledar10 а если ввести реПт ?

Comment: @splash58 Поправил ```/(^Петр)/gi```